# Retrieve value from open external API - visual studio - javascript - AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, visual-studio

I would really appreciate some advice, I'm trying to retrieve information from an open API for the first time.

The API details are here,

https://data.police.uk/docs/method/neighbourhood-locate/

I want to retrieve the 'force' and 'neighbourhood' values and save them into variables, I want to save them as variables as I'm then calling googlemaps to display the KML map.  I managed to get quite far on other sections of my code, such as geocoding a user inputted address and retrieving the Long/Lat, but I am now struggling to send the long/lat to the external API and save the response.

I've hardcoded the long/lat into the below URL for this advice request, I think I'm getting a response from the API but failing to capture the values into my variables.  The debugger shows the following response, {"force":"metropolitan","neighbourhood":"00BK17N"}, below is my code,

```
        var ForceId; //returned from the API
        var Neighbourhood; //returned from the API
        accessURL = "https://data.police.uk/api/locate-neighbourhood?q=51.500617,-0.124629"
        //Use the zip code and return all market ids in area.
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: accessURL,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function (data) {


                ForceId.push(val.force);
                Neighbourhood.push(val.Neighbourhood)

                console.log(ForceId);
                console.log(Neighbourhood);

            }})
```

Comment: When I capture the output of 'data' using the console log I see the following.... [object Object]{readyState: 4, status: 200, statusText: "success"}....so 'data' doesn't contain the response I need...I then added both 'error' and 'complete' as console log shows an error.....script1004: : Expected ';locate-neighbourhood (1,9).....when I click on the error within console log, it does contain the response I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a few mistakes, after seeing the responses were coming back as errors for its syntax, I adjusted some settings, I removed contenttype as 'application/JSON' and the response could be seen in the consolelog to contain the needed parameters.  I'm not sure of the implications of doing this or if its bad practice as I'm extremely new at this, its my first attempt at working with API's.  So other may advise better.

```
   function GetPolice(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            //        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: accessURL,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {

                ForceId = data.force;
                Neighbourhood = data.neighbourhood;        

            },
        })                   

    }
```

If your new at this, then my suggestion is to tinker with 'success, error, complete' to see what responses are being returned to consolelog.  Have a look at what your 'datatype' should be from the external API.   Again, i'm not best placed to give advice but hope other new people find this helpful.

I now need to make the above a callback response, as it completes the function before the responsehas been recieved, I wish to use the response in another fucntion elsewhere, but thats a different challenge :)